# English sentence to symbols in Quantification logic

Tags: logic

Some diamonds are used for adornment.  Only things worn as jewels or applied as cosmetics are used for adornment.  Diamonds are never applied as cosmetics.  Nothing worn as a jewel is properly used if it has an industrial application.  Some diamonds have industrial application.  Therefore, some diamonds are not properly used.

I don't know how to translate this in symbols. Can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a bunch of predicates:
$$\begin{align}
Diamond(x)&\iff \text{$x$ is a diamond} \\
Adornment(x)&\iff \text{$x$ is used for adornment} \\
WornAsJewel(x)&\iff \text{$x$ is worn as a jewel} \\
AppliedAsCosmetic(x)&\iff \text{$x$ is applied as a cosmetic} \\
ProperlyUsed(x)&\iff \text{$x$ is properly used} \\
HasIndustrialApplication(x)&\iff \text{$x$ has an industrial application}. \\
\end{align}$$
The sentences can be translated as follows:

- $(\exists x)\,(Diamond(x)\land Adornment(x))$
- $(\forall x)\,(Adornment(x)\to (Diamond(x)\lor AppliedAsCosmetic(x)))$
- $(\forall x)\,(Diamond(x)\to \neg\, AppliedAsCosmetic(x))$
- $(\forall x)\,((HasIndustrialApplication(x)\land WornAsJewel(x)) \to \neg\, ProperlyUsed(x))$
- $(\exists x)\,(Diamond(x)\land HasIndustrialApplication(x))$
- $(\exists x)\,(Diamond(x)\land \neg\,ProperlyUsed(x))$